# Google analytics doesn' t count requests from jmeter

Tags: apache, google-analytics, jmeter

I am testing my website (which calls google anlytics) with jmeter and all my responses are ok, I can even see the response data, but google anlytics doesn't show anything.
Does that  means that my requests failed?

This is test plan

```
 Test Plan 
   Thread Group
       http header Manager
       http cache manager
       Sample Request to my website
   View Results Tree
```

Answer (score 3):

JMeter is not a browser so it does not execute javascript inside the html pages , where typically google analytics calls are:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/

So it is not a real problem.

Looking at your test plan, it contains elements that are not ok during load test as they consume a lot of resources, like View Results Tree:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html (16.6)

Answer (score 0):

In general it is also considered a poor performance practice to include third party items where you do not have direct written permission to test from the site owners.   If you do find an error in Google Analytics just who would you report it to and what would be your reconciliation path to ensure that it is fixed prior to your release?

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)